# Автоматическое секционирование таблиц MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть две таблицы

> tab1
>
> | id | time |
>
> tab2
>
> | id | id_tab1 | value |

Нужно секционировать обе таблицы, в первой таблице диапазоном будет `time`, а во второй таблице диапазоном будет  `id_tab1`, начальное и конечно значение в секции таблицы `tab1.id`

один из вариантов который мне пришел на ум:

- создать секции для `tab1` на 10 лет в перед. с 2013-01-01 до 2020-01-01.
- создать событие которое будет запускаться раз в месяц. Будет производится выборка первого и последнего значения секции прошедшего периода и для `tab2` будет разбиваться последняя секция, отсекая прошедший месяц.

**разделение секции происходит по алгоритму:**

- скинуть функцию (`DROP PARTITION FUNCTION muFun`).
- создание вновь данной функции.
- применение функции с указанием дополнительного диапазона разделения(`ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION myFun() SPLIT RANGE (500)`)

После применения данной функции я так понимаю таблица по новой будет секционироваться? Или когда я сбрасываю функцию (`DROP`), я сбрасываю только функцию, и если при повторном создании ее, я укажу те же диапазоны, которые были в данной функции изначально, изменения претерпит только та секция в которой я буду изменять диапазон ранжирования или же все таки вся таблица будет секционироваться по новой?

Comment: Классный вопрос! Вообще не знал, что бывает секционирование

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужно сбрасывать функцию, чтобы добавить новый период. Просто добавляете командой

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [имя функции]() SPLIT RANGE (GETDATE())
```

У нас такая команда выполняется в джобе раз в сутки, в этом же джобе последняя партиция переносится во временную таблицу:

```
ALTER TABLE [таблица] SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.[имя функции](граница для переноса) TO [временная таблица]
```

После чего временная таблица транкейтится

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [временная таблица]
```

А в основной таблице последняя перенесенная партиция сливается с предыдущей:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [имя функции]() MERGE RANGE (граница для переноса)
```

Это самый быстрый способ избавления от лишних данных в партиционированных таблицах - собственно для этого во многом партиционирование и было сделано.
В SQL Server 2016 работа с партициями еще упростилась - вы можете транкейтить сразу отдельные партиции, не перенося их во временные таблицы.