# Aвтоматическое создание разделов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли в MSSQL как и в Oracle автоматическое создание разделов?

По типу:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (EVENTTIME)
INTERVAL( NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY'))
(  
    PARTITION P0 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2018-01-01 00:00:00')
    LOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE USERS
    LOB (MESSAGE) STORE AS (TABLESPACE  USERS)
);
```

Если да, то скинте доки на примеры или что-то похожее.

Comment: [Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: И так, я нашел ответ на собственный вопрос
Если кому понадобится
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/250099/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-mssql-2012